# Screen scraping a webserver using its IP address instead of its domain name

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen-scraping

Is this possible? It works when baseUrl = "http://mashable.com" but won't work when I give it an IP address.

```
<script src='https://raw.github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js'></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function () {

baseUrl = "https://12.34.56.78:8000/";
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl,
    type: "get",
    dataType: "",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Yeah we are om jere");
    });
});
```

Comment: "won't work"... what do you mean it won't work? do you see an error?

Comment: That's going to be difficult, as many websites may be hosted on the same server, thus sharing the same IP. It works with the domain name because your client sends it in the `Host` header along with the `GET` request.

Comment: Thank you! that's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: You asked for it :) and I included a couple of examples too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's going to be difficult, as many websites may be hosted on the same server, thus sharing the same IP. It works with the domain name because your client sends it in the Host header along with the `GET` request.

See this curl output for Stack Overflow:

```
C:\Users\Yeah>curl --head -i -v stackoverflow.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 198.252.206.140...
* Connected to stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.140) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: stackoverflow.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< [...]
```

You can see the domain name is being passed as a header.
If I, instead, try a query with the IP address found above it results in a 404 error:

```
C:\Users\Yeah>curl --head -i -v 198.252.206.140/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 198.252.206.140...
* Connected to 198.252.206.140 (198.252.206.140) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: 198.252.206.140
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< [...]
```

As a counter-example, though, here's what I get if I try to do something similar with the Facebook website:

```
C:\Users\Yeah>curl --head -i -v --insecure -L https://www.facebook.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 31.13.93.3...
* Connected to www.facebook.com (31.13.93.3) port 443 (#0)
* [SSL stuff ...]
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: www.facebook.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< [...]
```

And if I then try with the IP address above:

```
C:\Users\Yeah>curl --head -i -v --insecure -L https://31.13.93.3/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 31.13.93.3...
* Connected to 31.13.93.3 (31.13.93.3) port 443 (#0)
* [SSL stuff ...]
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: 31.13.93.3
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: http://www.facebook.com/
Location: http://www.facebook.com/
< [...]

<
* Connection #0 to host 31.13.93.3 left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://www.facebook.com/'
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 31.13.93.3...
* Connected to www.facebook.com (31.13.93.3) port 80 (#1)
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: www.facebook.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< [...]

<
* Connection #1 to host www.facebook.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://www.facebook.com/'
* Found bundle for host www.facebook.com: 0x6097814fe0
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 31.13.93.3...
* Connected to www.facebook.com (31.13.93.3) port 443 (#2)
* [SSL stuff ...]
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: www.facebook.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< [...]
```

Here `-L` (follow redirects) and `--insecure` (accept any certificate) are needed to make cUrl ultimately connect to the Facebook website, but these are usual client (i.e. browser) operations.

So that really depends on the particular website and server configuration you want to screen scrap.